# How to shape data for video classification task

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, video-processing

I want to use deep learning methods in order to solve a video classification problem.

My inputs are videos of different length, max 3 minutes long.

For each video I downsampled each frame to have a shape=(112,112,3) heigh,width and channels respectively:

```
#  maxFrame is the number of frames of the longest video, dir is a list of directory where video are stored
X = []
for i in dir:
    for filename in os.listdir(i):
       cap = cv2.VideoCapture(i + filename)  
       vid = []
       while (cap.isOpened()):
          ret, frame = cap.read()
          if ret:
             vid.append(frame)
          else:
             break
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        gc.collect()
        #vid = np.asarray(vid)
        reshape_frames = reshapeVid(vid)
        reshape_frames = np.asarray(reshape_frames)
        X.append(np.asarray(reshape_frames))


X = np.asarray(X)
X = sequence.pad_sequences(X, maxlen=maxFrame)

def reshapeVid(frames):
    width = 112
    height = 112
    channel = 3
    dim = ( width,height)
    reshape_frames = np.zeros((len(frames), height, width, channel))
    for i, img in enumerate(frames):
        resized = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
        reshape_frames[i,:,:,:] = resized
    return reshape_frames
```

I'm hitting memory error issues when I do `X = np.asarray(X)` or  `X = sequence.pad_sequences(X, maxlen=maxFrame)`

I tried to reduce the number of frames: vid = vid[:100] and the preproccesing works but still hit memory issue when fit the keras model.

How can I rappresent an entire video in a numpy array in order to feed it to a keras model?